# How do I start multiple Windows Services at once, with one command?

Tags: windows, windows-services

My primary computer for programming is the same computer I use for gaming etc. So to increase speed while gaming I turned off services like Apache, MySQL, Subversion etc. from starting at boot as I use it about 50/50 for gaming/programming.

This is fine most of the time but it's a bit of a nuisance to start them all separately.

Could someone show me how to write a batch file or something similar to start all the services?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can write a batch file like

```
net start "Service Name"
```

There should be a way to dependency link the services together also, so when one starts all the others will too.  I'll see if I can find the switch to do that.

EDIT:

I haven't tried this, but this should tell you where to find in the registry to make the services dependent on each other and all start automatically:

http://www.softwaretipsandtricks.com/windowsxp/articles/490/1/Removing-Service-Dependencies

Answer (score 4):

You can also have the services start in parallel by calling:

> SC START servicename

I don't know if that helps...

I wouldn't mess with the dependencies for services unless you *really* know what you're doing.

Comment: For this question, 'sc' is the better method as it starts the service asynchronously, moving onto the next batch command.

Answer (score 3):

The command for starting a service is `"net start <servicename>`".  Just add the ones you need to a file called Something.bat and run it.  simple. :)

`net stop <service name>` will also stop them.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using powershell, you can do this:

```
"service1", "service2" | %{ start-service $_ }
```

To explain the above, it's as follows:

1. create an array containing "service1" and "service2"
2. pipe that array to the `foreach` command (which is the `%` sign)
3. the `foreach` command will run the code block (delimited by `{ }` ), and the "current item" is represented by `$_`
4. It will therefore run `start-service` on each of the things in your array

Answer (score 2):

simply use powershell if you have a common name

Start Services

```
Get-Service *pattern* | start-service
```

Stop Services

```
Get-Service *pattern* | stop-service
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a tad late on this, though I was researching something similar.

create a batch file and in that batch file use the sc command:

sc start "first servicename"
sc start "second servicename"

and so on...
save the batch file and either double click it to run it, or schedule it to run accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Like other answers mentioned, writing a batch/cmd file works wonders.

```
@echo off

echo Press any key to start the Services
echo ===================================

pause

echo Starting Apache
net start Apache

echo Starting MySQL
net start MySQL

echo Starting Subversion
net start Subversion

echo == Services have started ==

timeout 3
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way:

1. Install ps tools (it has a lot of really cool cmd line tools for developers)
2. One of the tools that ps tools comes with is   [PsService](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897542.aspx)
3. you can start stop your services using start and stop

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm late to the party , however here is exactly what you need.
[ProgramUtilityv1](https://github.com/bluelurker/utilities/tree/master/ProgramUtilityv1)
I was looking for such application too, so i wrote it myself. It works only on Windows and that too on Windows Vista and above.I'll soon release a linux version too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start several services at once and still wait for them to start you can do the following:

```
workflow work {
    param(
        [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
        [Collections.Generic.List[string]]$list)
    
    Foreach -parallel ($s in $list)
    { 
        Start-Service $s         
    }
}

$list = Get-Service -Name "servicename*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | foreach{$_.DisplayName}
work -list $list
```

With this:

- you dont have inmediate return. If you dont care if service-start failed you can go with sc, net start or ps tools options.
- Services are started at the same time

Answer (score -1):

```sh
sc start Service1 && sc start Service2
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from additional information around why this fixes the issue, as well as to be correctly formatted.